# how to execute copy/paste using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute a paste to a local variable already exist to an input text with selenium webdriver in java.
for this I used this method:

```
public static void copyText(final String id, final String text) throws Exception {
        waitForJQueryProcessing(DRIVER, N_30);
        WebElement elem = DRIVER.findElement(By.id(id));
        DRIVER.findElement(By.id(id)).clear();
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection strSel = new StringSelection(text);
        clipboard.setContents(strSel, null);
        elem.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v", text));
        System.out.println(text);

    }
```

When I execute the test, i will appear empty I don't know why ?

Comment: Your code is all over the place.  You're creating a web element variable, but then not using it to clear, instead re-looking-up the element again and clearing it.  Harmless but redundant, perhaps.  You're also doing a clipboard.setContents(strSel, null) which I would interpret as CLEARING the clipboard, but then you paste the (empty) clipboard with a control-v combined with the text?  Why aren't you just doing a sendkeys of the text?

Comment: I tried with sendkeys but it does not accept
so i thought about just copy the text variable in the input

Comment: Are you getting a specific error with sendKeys or does it just not send anything?  Perhaps you should show the relevant HTML code for the web element you're trying to access.  It might not be an editable text field.

Comment: I write a script test to test my application
so that I can insert the date on the image inserted html but I can not do it with sendkeys
either I just copy the value into the input text or try to get it with the calendar
Do you understand the context now?

Comment: The screenshot of the HTML code helps, although generally they prefer that be posted as formatted text here, but it's better than none at all.  Can you add a screenshot of the calendar control to the original post, please?

Comment: I added but i don't undersant hy the text doesn't appear in the input text

Comment: The screenshot you added was the same as the other - I needed to see the actual screen of the web app/page.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now that the calendar control is part of both screenshots - I'm visually impaired and didn't see it at first.  I'm not sure why it isn't accepting input, there's nothing in the HTML that hints that it might not, but it does appear to be a non-standard control (at least to me).  Perhaps you might need to send a click to the control before doing a sendkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code and check if it could help you.

```
String CopyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath to order id")).getText();
driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody
/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(myOrderText ));
```

or try the below code:

```
// or any locator strategy that you find suitable 
        WebElement locOfOrder = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element to be copied"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(locOfOrder).doubleClick().build().perform();
// catch here is double click on the text will by default select the text 
// now apply copy command 

driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"c"));

    // now apply the command to paste
    driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to copy the *character sequence* from *clipboard* to a `<input>` element you can use the following solution:

```
//imports
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
//other lines of code
WebElement elem = DRIVER.findElement(By.id(id));
elem.clear();
String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
elem.sendKeys(data);
```