# Capture value present in input Text Box in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am unable to capture the text present in the input Text Box. I can see that the text in the Text Box, but the same is not present in the html DOM. As result, I am unable to capture it. I tried using getAttribute('value'), but that didn't work as the value attribute itself is not present. I have tried using getText(), but that didn't work too.

Here's the html code for the input Text box:

`<input id="param_defvalue" type="text" class="inputbox" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 0px;">`

Note : I am not entering the value after opening the Web Page, the value is pre-populated.

Answer (score 0):

If is a text box your solution could be

```
WebElement locOfOrder = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element to be copied"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(locOfOrder).doubleClick().build().perform();
// catch here is double click on the text will by default select the text 
// now apply copy command 

driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"c"));

    // now apply the command to paste
    driver.findElement (By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"));
```

Copied from [how to execute copy/paste using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197208/how-to-execute-copy-paste-using-selenium-webdriver/51212084)

Comment: Thanks. Copy is working fine. But I would like to copy the text and write same into a file.

Comment: You do not do that with selenium it only interacts with browser. You can do it with Java https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp or something else if you use other program language.

Comment: I tried doing it by using javascript copy and paste but it is returning undefined